# Prove that the vectors are linearly independent

Tags: vector-spaces

Show that vectors $v_{1}, v_{2}, ..., v_{n} \in V$ are linearly independent only when $v_{1}, v_{1} + v_{2}, ..., \sum_{i \in [n]} v_{i}$ are linearly independent.
I know it must be true, because its the definition of linearly independent vectors, but I don't know how can I prove that.

Answer (score 0):

We're given that if $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i=0$ then all $c_i$ are $0$. You want to prove if$$\sum_{i=1}^nC_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^iv_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i=0,\,c_i:=\sum_{j=i}^nC_j$$then  all $C_i$ are $0$. Certainly all the $c_i$ are $0$. Then $C_i=c_i-c_{i+1}=0$ for $i<n$, while $C_n=c_n=0$.